# Stack Overflow Exception While Using Session Inside Getter Setter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a private variable whose type is List. I have getter and setter functions to initialize my variable. But it doesn't work as i expected.

## CODE

```
private List<Flight> flightsInCart
        {
            get { return (List<Flight>)(Session["Flight"] = flightsInCart); }
            set { flightsInCart = value/*(List<Flight>)Session["Flight"]*/; }
        }


public ActionResult AddToVoucher(string flightCode)
        {
            if(flightsInCart == null)
            {
                flightsInCart = new List<Flight>();              
            }
            FlightRepository repo = FlightRepository.Singleton;
            var flight = repo.GetFlightByCode(flightCode);
            flightsInCart.Add(flight);
            var flights = repo.GetAllFlights();
            return View("Index",flights);
        }
```

## ERROR

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

In the if condition, execution automatically stops and i can't debug it. What is the wrong part of the code? Thanks.

Note : Initialize that variable solved my problem but i expected to get **NullPointerException** not **StackOverflow**. Thats why i asked this question. Please reconsider it before voting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is in this line

```
get { return (List<Flight>)(Session["Flight"] = flightsInCart); }
```

Your property is named `flightsInCart`. So from inside your getter, you call the getter **again**. This leads to the `StackOverflowException` as you create an infinite recursion.

The same goes for your setter.

You probably wanted to create a backing field and name the property with a capital letter:

```
// backing field
private List<Flight> flightsInCart;

// property
private List<Flight> FlightsInCart // <- with capital (c# naming convention)
{
     get { return (List<Flight>)(Session["Flight"] = flightsInCart); }
     set { flightsInCart = value/*(List<Flight>)Session["Flight"]*/; }
}
```